# Conditional pstcmd with savepnpc in EMC Networker

Tags: backup, networker

I need to delete some files if they have been backed up.

I'm trying to find how to do this with savepnpc command, but it seems that pstcmd is run unconditionally, so even if the backup fails (e.g. there are no tapes available) the files are deleted, which is not what I need.

How could that be done?

Comment: You could try querying using `nsradmin` or `mminfo` in the post script, however I am not sure if the group status is already success or fail at that point.....

Answer (score -1):

The way to solve this is by creating a tempfile on successful completion of the precmd. Then have the postcmd check for the tempfile before running.  Be sure to delete the tempfile in the postcmd.

Comment: successful completion of the precmd does not help. I need to be sure of successful backup.